How to decompose this relation (A,B,C) with 1MVD (A-->>B), 1FD (AB ->C) to comply with 4NF?
As the title, how to decompose this relation (A,B,C) having one MVD (A-->>B), one functional dependency AB ->C to comply with 4NF?
I think it's like impossible ? Is that correct? because otherwise, it breaks preservation of FD.

According to wikip https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_dependency " exists when there are at least three attributes ...". Then MVD (A-->>B) induces MVD (A-->>C). So you should be able to partition into (A,B) and (A,C); then Join those to get back to what you started with. But that contradicts the FD. In any case, if (AB -> C) -- and you don't have (A->B) nor (A->C) -- that's all the attributes of the relation. So you can't decompose. How could you split out any attribute? Have you told us all of the question?
